# Change Style of the Letterhead in Koma Script scrlttr2

Tags: color, koma-script, scrlttr2

I am using the scrlttr2 class of Koma Script and I would like to use a different color for the letterhead, which contains my address on the top of the page.

Is there a simple way to apply the command `\color{colorname}` at the whole letterhead? Or, to stay more general, to apply a style such as `\sffamily` etc.?

The only way I figured out is to put the command in **each** definition of `\setkomavar`, but it does not even fully solve the problem because the separators are not affected.

Many thanks!

Comment: `\addtokomafont{fromaddress}{\color{red!40!black}}\addtokomafont{fromname}{\color{red!40!black}}`

Comment: @Johannes_B Can you answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

The code at the bottom leads to the next image.

[image: pietroScrlttrColour]

```
\documentclass[fromphone=true]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Pietro}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Strawberry fields\\ Land of jam}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{555-jam}
\addtokomafont{fromaddress}{\color{red!70!black}}
\addtokomafont{fromname}{\color{red!70!black}}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Marmelade\\Chilichutneytown}
    \opening{My sweet dear,}
    \lipsum
    \closing{your jam boy}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```